# Email::Sender how to attach file in Perl?

Tags: perl, email, email-attachments

System: Perl 5.26.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. There is a subroutine that does email in a file called util2.pl. The subroutine is called mailadming() and has a bunch of parameters like the SMTP server info, to and from addresses, etc. util2.pl is `require`d into the main program.

I've been searching for about 2 hours on various sites and Google, and reading the manual on Email::Sender and I cannot seem to find how to attach a file when using Email::Sender. I am upgrading a machine and was using Mail::Sender but Mail::Sender is deprecated for Email::Sender, and docs are sparse on Email::Sender.

I could not find any info at all on file attachments in Email::Sender docs.

Since Mail::Sender is not updated anymore it would be a bad idea to continue using that. We have a lot invested in Perl so we just can't change tools at this point.

1. Can anyone help me out please?
2. Should I use another email module for Perl? Email::Sender seems to be updated the most often and most recent.

EDIT: This is the code I have so far:

```
my $email = Email::Stuffer->new(
        text_body=>$body,
        subject=>$subjparam,
        from=>$from, # or use ->from($email1, $email2...)
        transport=>Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
            host => $smtpserver,
            port => $smtpport,
            username => $smtpuser,
            password => $smtppw,
            }),
        );
```

The error I get right now is: 
`Can't use string ("text_body") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Email/Stuffer.pm line 224.`

**I can't just create the email and send it in one shot,** I have to create the email, look for other options to add to it (like CC addresses and if I need to attach a file), etc. And code I got from Perl Maven just doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

There are two components to the process, constructing the email and sending it. Email::Sender only handles the latter, and it shows how to use Email::Simple to construct simple emails. To construct more advanced emails like those with attachments, you want the more powerful [Email::MIME](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME), and there is a wrapper of Email::MIME and Email::Sender together called [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer), which provides easy APIs for attaching files.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Stuffer;
my $mail = Email::Stuffer->to($to)->from($from)->subject($subj)->text_body($text);

$mail->attach_file('/path/to/file.txt'); # guesses MIME type
# or if you have the file data in memory
$mail->attach($contents, name => 'foo.dat', filename => 'foo.dat',
           content_type => 'application/octet-stream');

# to change the transport
$mail->transport('SMTP', host => ...);
$mail->transport(Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new(...));

$mail->send_or_die;
```

Comment: Thank you. The docs are not real clear on it's use. If I use `->send_or_die` can I specify an error message in a paramater like `->send_or_die("Email could not be sent.")` ?

Comment: @Bulrush No, but you can catch and rethrow exceptions easily enough in Perl: http://mvp.kablamo.org/essentials/try-catch/, or you can use `->send` and die yourself if it returns false.

Comment: Do I really have to specify the content type manually in my program? If so, where do I find a list of content types? Most of my files that will be attached to emails will be XLS or XLSX files. Some will be RTF files.

Comment: @Bulrush No, it will guess it from the file extension, but it's not a bad idea to be explicit anyway. A list of many common types is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

Comment: @Bulrush You can also use [MIME::Types](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Types) to translate between extensions and mime types.

Comment: @Bulrush The Email::Stuffer guessing is very limited (it doesn't appear to contain any of the types you mentioned), MIME::Types will recognize them more completely.

Comment: would you mind expanding your answer by showing how to create the $email object and set options like to address, from address, SMTP server info, port, SMTP username, SMTP password, and file attachment? I thought the create routine was called "create" but it's not. See my question above, I added the code I have so far.

Comment: @Bulrush that is the Email::MIME api. The documentation shows an example of using Email::MIME in case you want to dig into the details but the synopsis shows how headers are normally set.

Comment: @Bulrush Added more examples.

Comment: now I see my problem. I've never seen any syntax like in line 4 of your example. Typically parameters are passed a different way from the examples I've seen. I'll try it out. And your example works in Perl 5.26? It doesn't require Perl6?

Comment: @Bulrush It is a little weird but somewhat similar to chained attribute setters in some other systems like Mojo::Base. It also does have a `new` method that might work more like you expect but I tend to stick to the approaches with examples. Perl 6 has been renamed to Raku and has not been relevant to continued Perl development for a long time.

Comment: @Bulrush Some of your confusion may be expecting consistency that isn't really there; there is no "one way" to set attributes on objects, or even create objects in Perl, so different CPAN modules have different approaches, though `new` and attribute accessors are both common at least.

Comment: It's important to read the docs for the particular module you're using and not assume it will work like other classes, with the exception of when it's using a well known object system like Moose, Moo, or Mojo::Base.